# Difference between using ID+IDREF and direct Type in XML Schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, idref

I am new to XSD and have a question about the difference between the following two schemas?

1) Direct use of IDREF and ID to limit the selection to another element within the file:

```
<xsd:element name="policy" >
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="actor-def" 
                   type="tns:actor-def"/>                        
      <xsd:element name="actor-system-def" 
                   type="tns:actor-system-def"/>           
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:complexType name="actor-def">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="actor-system" 
                 type="tns:actor-system-type"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="name" 
                 type="xsd:ID" 
                 use="required" />
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="actor-system-type">
  <xsd:attribute name="name" 
                 type="xsd:IDREF" 
                 use="required" />
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="actor-system-def">
  <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:ID" use="required" />
  <xsd:attribute name="url" type="xsd:anyURI" use="required" />
</xsd:complexType>
```

2)  Setting the type of the element directly to the other element type:

```
<xsd:element name="policy">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="actor-def" 
                   type="tns:actor-def"/>
      <xsd:element name="actor-system-def" 
                   type="tns:actor-system-def"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:complexType name="actor-def">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="actor-system" 
                 type="tns:actor-system-def"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="name" 
                   type="xsd:ID" 
                   use="required" />
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="actor-system-def">
  <xsd:attribute name="name" 
                 type="xsd:ID" 
                 use="required" />
  <xsd:attribute name="url" 
                 type="xsd:anyURI" 
                 use="required" />
</xsd:complexType>
```

I faced some issues with using the first approach when combining it with JAXB in the translated java classes and someone suggested in response to my other post using the second method. However, I am not sure what is the main difference between these two schemas and which one is the right one for my application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML IDREF in JAXB returns the wrong class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050709/xml-idref-in-jaxb-returns-the-wrong-class)